# How to return boolean from logining user

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I am doing mvvm project in kotlin and I use room to login and register new user.

Part of code:

```
    view.login_btn.setOnClickListener {
        val takenUsername = username.text.toString()
        val takenPassword = password.text.toString()

        if(takenUsername.isEmpty() || takenPassword.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Fill all columns", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            //Zwraca unity (naprawic to a nie null
            val userEntity  = mMainActivityViewModel.checkLogin(takenUsername,takenPassword)

            if(userEntity.equals(null)){
                Toast.makeText(context!!, "Bad login or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{

                Toast.makeText(context!!, "Login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

I dont understand why but this function returns a unit not a null.Which i completly doesnt know.

Could someone propose what should I put instead of null in line 11?

Comment: Here full class https://github.com/polonez-byte-112/Querto/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/querto/fragments/login/LoginFragment.kt

Comment: Could you share your function checkLogin(name: String, password: String) of ViewModel? I think returns nothing, so the result will be Unit, but i need to see the code.

Comment: on github is full code

Comment: how can it return something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are following wrong approach my friend. You need to use live data to get the callback from view model.

```
private fun setupLoginObserver() {
    mMainActivityViewModel.loginStatus.observe(this, Observer { isValidUser ->
        if (isValidUser) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Bad login or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
}
```

You can call this method from onViewCreated()

Your button click listener should be like:

```
view.login_btn.setOnClickListener {
        val takenUsername = username.text.toString()
        val takenPassword = password.text.toString()

        if (takenUsername.isEmpty() || takenPassword.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Fill all columns", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            //Check user is valid or not in db and you will get the callback on line #
            mMainActivityViewModel.checkLogin(takenUsername, takenPassword)
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
fun checkLogin(username: String, password: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.loginUser(username, password)?.let {
            mutableLoginStatus.postValue(true)
        } ?: mutableLoginStatus.postValue(false)
    }
}
```

UserRepository:

```
suspend fun loginUser(username: String, password: String): User? {
    return userDao.loginUser(username, password)
}
```

And Finally UserDao:

```
@Query("SELECT user_table.* FROM user_table WHERE username= :username AND password=:password")
   suspend fun  loginUser(username: String, password: String): User?
```

I have made few required changes in your code and pushed in this branch.

https://github.com/parmeshtoyou/Querto/tree/user_validate_through_live_data_stackoverflow

You can review the changes.

Let me know if you need any clarification.

Happy Coding.

Comment: thanks You so much.I mostly write in java and its very helpfull. I am waiting for my book from kotlin and clean code so i will make future project more efficient.Also its my first project in mvvm (connecting everything together) .Thanks you soo much. You are my saviour

Comment: at current moment i am adding recycler view to this app but when i finish this i will ask for sure xd.Thanks so much again

Comment: Could you describe for  me  isValidUser , loginStatus and mutableLoginStatus? I figure out login and mutable login is livedata etc and they are stored in viewmodel but isValidUser is a local variable in loginFragment right? Should loginstatus be declared at start in viewmodel?

Comment: i understand now after merge.Thanks you soo much <3

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `function` to return a boolean, like this

```
view.login_btn.setOnClickListener {
        loginUser()
    }

fun loginUser():Boolean{
        val takenUsername = username.text.toString()
        val takenPassword = password.text.toString()

        if(takenUsername.isEmpty() || takenPassword.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Fill all columns", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return false
        }else{
            //Zwraca unity (naprawic to a nie null
            val userEntity  = mMainActivityViewModel.checkLogin(takenUsername,takenPassword)

            if(userEntity.equals(null)){
                Toast.makeText(context!!, "Bad login or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return false
            }else{

                Toast.makeText(context!!, "Login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return true

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: checklogin should return boolean not login

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM Architecture we can use LiveData, To get the value from ViewModel

In ViewModel, we can validate the Login success or not,

```
fun checkLogin(username: String, password: String) {
   // Perform Login validation
    validUser.setValue(true) // set the livedata as true on login validation Success
    validUser.setValue(false) // set the livedata as true on login validation falied
}
```

Inactivity you can Observe the LivedataChanges

```
mMainActivityViewModel.validUser.observe(this, Observer<Boolean> {validUser:Boolean? ->
            if(validUser){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
       else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        })
```

In OnClickListener

```
view.login_btn.setOnClickListener {
        val takenUsername = username.text.toString()
        val takenPassword = password.text.toString()

        if(takenUsername.isEmpty() || takenPassword.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Fill all columns", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            // just call the method and set the Livedata value based on the validation 
            mMainActivityViewModel.checkLogin(takenUsername,takenPassword)

        }
    }
```